# Elements in array O(nlogn) complexity method for finding pairs

Tags: c, complexity-theory

Okay, I keep getting stuck with the complexity here. There is an array of elements, say `A[n]`. Need to find all pairs so that `A[i]>A[j]` and also `i < j`.

So if it is `{10, 8, 6, 7, 11}`, the pairs would be `(10,8) (10, 6), (10,7) and so on...`

I did a merge sort in nlogn time and then a binary search for the entire array again in nlogn to get the indices of the elements in the sorted array.

So `sortedArray={6 7 8 10 11}` and `index={3 2 0 1 4}`

Irrespective of what I try, I keep getting another `n^2` time in the complexity when I begin loops to compare. I mean, if I start for the first element i.e. 10, it is at `index[2]` which means there are 2 elements less than it. So if `index[2]<index[i]` then they can be accepted but that increases the complexity. Any thoughts? I don't want the code, just a hint in the right direction would be helpful.

Thanks. Everything i have been doing in C and time complexity is important here [c](/questions/tagged/c)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the problem - but won't the array `[10,9,8,...,1]` produce `(10,9),...,(10,1),(9,8),...(9,1),...` as pairs - and there are `O(n^2)` of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result consists of O(n^2) elements, so any attempt to iterate through all pairs will be O(n^2).

Comment: If a[i]>a[j] and i<j it is basically looking for an unsorted array that is in the process of being sorted...I am sure this can be found somewhere in the merge sort algorithm but I just cannot pinpoint the place to get it to list it...any help? If it can be identified within the merge sort algorithm before the swapping is actually done, then we have it in O(nlogn) time...

Comment: What will you be doing with the result? Setting up a data structure that allows O(1) access to each result element can be done in O(nlogn), but referencing (for example printing) them all is O(n^2) because there are O(n^2) elements.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this in under `O(N^2)`, because the number of pairs that the algorithm will produce when the original array sorted in descending order is `N(N-1)/2`. You simply cannot produce `O(N^2)` results in `O(N*LogN)` time.

Comment: N(N-1)/2, but yeah, what he said.